# After creating custom post type, URL to custom posts are invalid

Tags: custom-post-types

So I created a custom post type like

```
add_action('init', 'create_post_type');

function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type(
    'portfolio', 
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Portfolio',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add New Portfolio Item',
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Portfolio Item'
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
      'menu_position' => 5
    )
  );
}
```

When I add a new custom post (http://localhost/wordpress/portfolio/portfolio-item-3/) and try going to that page, I get a 404. Whats wrong?

**UPDATE**

[This solution](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalink-to-custom-post-type-gives-me-404-error#post-1893539) works but what does it do and it sounds like its not good to keep flushing my rewrite rules isit?

> Add
>
> ```
> flush_rewrite_rules();
> ```
>
> after you call `register_post_type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that does is reset the rewrite rules. You could do the same by visiting the permalinks page and clicking save. You do need to reset them once but not every time. There is no need to flush every time you call register_post_type